# Google Colab won't display dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I want to display a dataframe `df_per_day` running the code in Google Colab as below:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=['count'])
    df['date'] = [d.floor('D') for d in df['count']]
    df_per_day = df.groupby('date')
    num_per_day = df_per_day.count()
    display(df_per_day)
```

where `df_list` is a list of timestamps:

```
Timestamp('2020-01-03 13:28:36.283000'),
Timestamp('2020-01-03 16:01:45.790000'),
Timestamp('2020-01-03 16:03:15.813000'),
...
```

However, Google Colab didn't not return the dataframe as I wanted but this line instead:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f8f6a287080>
```

Comment: you should display `display(num_per_day)` since `df_per_day` is just a groupby object not a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display is a function in the IPython.display module that runs the appropriate dunder method to get the appropriate data to ... display.

- try these instead
- df_per_day or print(df_per_day)