# Google Colab Not Displaying Plots or Pandas Dataframe

Tags: google-colaboratory

Colab is not displaying plots or pandas dataframes in any of my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge).  For example, *display(df)* gives the following error in a pop-up window:

```
Error
Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output.
This is probably because your Google account login access has expired or because third-party cookies are not allowed by your browser.

Please reload this page.
```

Arrays, Series, etc. will all display normally.  *print(df)* will also display the dataframe normally in a text-only format.  Also, running the same notebooks through binder (mybinder.org) displays the dataframes normally in all browsers.  I added [*.]googleusercontent.com to "allowed" third party cookies...no luck.  This issue seems isolated to displaying advanced objects in Colab.

Any solutions out there?  Appreciate the help.

Comment: What if you just type `df` as the last line of a cell? Also see the first line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807441/8508004) and see if Colab allows `from IPython.display import display` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55329863/8508004) suggests at one time it did)? What about the Colab specific display for Pandas ===> see [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/data_table.ipynb).

Comment: Thanks @Wayne.  `df` as the last line results in the same JavaScript error as `display(df)`.  `print(df)` works, albeit shows the _df_ in a plain text format.  Both `from IPython.display import display` and the Colab specific display still result in the same JavaScript error.  I could use `print(df)` as a workaround, but still am stumped about displaying plots.

Comment: Hmmm... Before saying `print(df)` will suffice, I'd caution you to figure it out because it may solve your plotting, too because it seems waayyy wrong. Is it only in this one notebook that stuff is messed up? I just opened the notebook about Data Table Display page about the data from [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/data_table.ipynb) and did some pandas stuff that I added in (didn't run any of the other code) and both `df` on a line alone and `display(df)` worked. I didn't need to do any import beyond pandas or try any of the other code in the notebook. ...

Comment: <continued> So based on that I would say you clobbered the display code (or have some other code 'shadowing' it) in that namespace and you need to restart and not clobber/shadow it. That being messed up would be consistent with problems with your plotting.

Comment: I’ve tried several notebooks - the problem is the same in all of them.  Even a brand new notebook with just:`plt.hist([1,2,3,4])` gives me the JavaScript error.  I’m now thinking the problem is a setting somewhere on my computer that’s blocking however Colab displays plots and Dataframes.

Comment: Something being blocked makes sense given all the symptoms. Can you try the same notebooks in your own account from a different computer on a different network?

Comment: Yep, I don't get the error with the same notebooks on my other computer.  Probably something with my computer or network.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good sleuthing.